# Trouble installing Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal, psychparser

This is my second time trying to install Ruby on my system.  This time I've following http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html.  I've followed the steps and keep getting hung up with the error below.  At this point, I've backtracked and removed RVM and Homebrew, but now I'm seeing this error. I've searched stack overflow, google, etc.  There are similar issues but they're all not related to system files.  Any ideas where I can start?

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 29 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

edit: .gemrc file

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri
update: --no-rdoc --no-rigem: --no-document
```

Comment: Do you have a `.gemrc` file and, if so, what does it look like?

Comment: Please show your `.gemrc` properly formatted in your question. It needs to be YAML, but I can't tell if it is based upon the formatting in the comment.

Comment: added to the question as requested. thank you for your help, @lurker